# gMapsFX netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx

im trying to use gmapsfx in my javafx program.

my code is this:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    mapView = new GoogleMapView();
    mapView.addMapInializedListener(this);
}    


    @Override
public void mapInitialized() {    
    MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
    options
        .center(new LatLong(40.7127, -74.0059))
        .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP)
        .zoom(12);
    map = mapView.createMap(options);
    mapView.setKey("");
    showMarker(40.748433, -73.985656, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Disc_Plain_red.svg/32px-Disc_Plain_red.svg.png");
    showMarker(40.713, -74.0135, "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Disc_Plain_blue.svg/32px-Disc_Plain_blue.svg.png");
}

/**
 * Adds a marker to the map.
 */
public void showMarker(double lat, double lng, String iconPath) {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options
        .icon(iconPath)
        .position(new LatLong(lat, lng));
    Marker marker = new Marker(options);
    map.addMarker(marker);
}
```

this is the error that i am having. i think im just missing something.....................................................

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: loadMapLibrary
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:146)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)


Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:146)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1509)
```

Comment: I spent 3 hours trying to figure out this error. Upon moving the project to another computer, the error was no longer present. The new computer had the same JRE, JDK version. So as a terrible and dissatisfying workaround, I spun up a VM with a clean environment and am working from there. It's something specific to my machine. The only thing I can think of is that the com.sun.webkit is out of date. No idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the key `mapView.setKey("");` in the initialize method of the controller, then the map loaded without error.